# Oracle SQL . Count based on two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a table:

```
JIRA_KEY   DATACENTER STATUS 
  1         US        CLOSED
  2         EM        CLOSED
  3         AP        CLOSED
  4         US        CLOSED
  5         EM        IN PROGRESS
  6         AP        CANCELLED
  7         US        IN PROGRESS
  8         US        CANCELLED  
  9         AP        CANCELLED  
 10         AP        IN PROGRESS
```

Expected Output:

```
Datacenter TotalJiras Closed InProgress Cancelled
EMEA          2       1        1           0
APAC          4       1        1           2
AMERICA       4       2        1           1
```

I tried creating a view:

```
create or replace view VW_JIRA_STATUS_BK AS 
SELECT count(JIRA_KEY) JIRA ,
  decode (substr(data_center,1,2),'EM', 'EMEA', 'AP', 'APAC', 'US', 'AMERICA') as REGION, 
  status 
from hw_jira_status 
group by data_center , status;

select * from VW_JIRA_STATUS_BK
```

does not display the result as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: General GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need *conditional aggregates* using CASE, one for each result column:

```
create or replace view VW_JIRA_STATUS_BK AS 
SELECT
   decode (substr(data_center,1,2),'EM', 'EMEA', 'AP', 'APAC', 'US', 'AMERICA') as REGION, 
   count(JIRA_KEY) AS TotalJiras,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'CLOSED' THEN 1 END) AS Closed,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'IN PROGRESS' THEN 1 END) AS InProgress,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'CANCELLED' THEN 1 END) AS Cancelled
from hw_jira_status 
group by data_center;  -- don't group by "Status"
```

Why do you apply a `SUBSTR` on `data_center` if it's two characters anyway?

Btw, I pefer Standard SQL's `CASE` over Oracle's deprecated `DECODE`:

```
CASE data_center
  WHEN 'EM' THEN 'EMEA'
  WHEN 'AP' THEN 'APAC'
  WHEN 'US' THEN 'AMERICA'
END as REGION,
```

Comment: That worked.  I replaced the decode substr code with case  as suggested 

.SELECT CASE data_center
  WHEN like 'EM%' THEN 'EMEA'
  WHEN like 'AP%' THEN 'APAC'
  WHEN like 'US%' THEN 'AMERICA'  , 

Good learning for me. Thank you